# Python minimize with different conditions

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, minimize

I am currently trying to find a replacement dataset of points for a large dataset of points. I want to define the points of the replacement dataset in such a way that they are irregular and thus describe the area optimally.
I have written a function "objective". This takes a numpy array, which contains x points. These points I would like to distribute optimized at the end. The function first calculates the intersection points on the original curve, then the area is calculated. The error is used as reference area. How do I make sure that I distribute the points "optimally"? How can I integrate conditions so that I set the limits of the dataset here?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.integrate import simps
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from numpy import trapz

# testpoints given by user
base_points_x = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1])
base_points_y = np.array([1,5,5.5,6,6.5,6.7,6.9,7,7.1,7.15])

# calculate the base area
base_area_trapz = trapz(base_points_y, x=base_points_x)
base_area_simps = simps(base_points_y, x=base_points_x)
print("base area =", round(base_area_trapz,4))
print("base area =", round(base_area_simps,4))

# 1. method, use a discrete small equal discretised number of points
dis_points = 5
first_points_x = np.linspace(base_points_x[0], base_points_x[-1], dis_points)
first_points_y = np.zeros(dis_points)

for n in range(0, dis_points):
    xa = np.argmin(base_points_x <= first_points_x[n])
    xb = np.argmax(base_points_x >= first_points_x[n])
    first_points_y[n] = np.interp(first_points_x[n], base_points_x, base_points_y)

#calculate the first area and difference
first_area_trapz = trapz(first_points_y, x=first_points_x)
first_area_simps = simps(first_points_y, x=first_points_x)

print("base area =", round(first_area_trapz, 4), round(base_area_trapz-first_area_trapz, 4))
print("base area =", round(first_area_simps, 4), round(base_area_simps-first_area_simps, 4))

# 2. method optimize the area
def objective(x):
    y = np.zeros(len(x))
    for n in range(0, len(x)):
        xa = np.argmin(base_points_x <= x[n])
        xb = np.argmax(base_points_x >= x[n])
        y[n] = np.interp(x[n], base_points_x, base_points_y)

    return base_area_trapz - trapz(y, x=x)

#guess values (taken from previous function)
x0 = first_points_x
res = minimize(objective, x0, method='nelder-mead', bounds=[])
```

For a better understanding I draw the Problem with an example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1GCB.png)

Comment: Could you maybe draw a visualization of exactly it is that you want? It's a bit unclear to me.

Comment: Thanks for the hint,  i did this, pls have a look at the question at the end.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is known as a *piecewise linear function approximation*. You can construct these easily using the Python `pwlf` package.

```
python3 -m pip install pwlf
```

Then, as an example of usage (warning, can be a bit slow):

```
import numpy as np
import pwlf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some dummy data.
X = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(X) * X * X

pwlffit = pwlf.PiecewiseLinFit(X, y)
# Atol sets absolute tolerance, see scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.
lfx = pwlffit.fit(5, atol=1e-10)
lfy = pwlffit.predict(lfx)

plt.plot(X, y, label="data")
plt.plot(lfx, lfy, label="approximation")
plt.scatter(lfx, lfy, label="breakpoints")
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Well, first of all thank u for the code and the example. But (here comes the but) it's only kind of what I am looking for. See the problem it, that the linear approximation in ur case does a great job, but the EndPoint's are not on the original data, witch is essentail. Pls can u check out the drawing i made?

Comment: @elPenguin If the endpoints *have* to be part of the original data you end up with a combinatorical problem, which usually is hard to solve optimally. What you could do as an approximation is perform the algorithm I have described here, and then select the closest point in the original dataset to the suggested breakpoints.